# How to register async middleware module within express.js app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, acl

I'm working on an express app that uses the [node_acl](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl) module with a MongoDB backend. I made a module that creates an instance of node_acl and configures it asynchronously. This middleware should be called as the second middleware on the stack to control request access.

```
// myModule.js

exports.init = function(callback) {
mongodb.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb", function(error, db) {
    var mongoBackend = new acl.mongodbBackend(db, 'acl_');
    acl = new acl(mongoBackend);    
    // Defining roles for acl 

    ....

    acl.addRoleParents('..', '..', function(err){
        if (err) callback(err, acl);
        acl.addRoleParents('..', '..', function(err){
            if (err) callback(err, acl);
            acl.addRoleParents('..', ['..','..'], function(err){
                if (err) {
                    callback(err, acl);
                } else {
                    callback(null, acl);
                };
            });
        });
    });
}); 
};
```

How can I register this module to be the second middleware of the stack? Do I need to edit myModule.js in some way?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module already [provides an Express middleware](https://github.com/OptimalBits/node_acl#middleware-numpathcomponents-userid-permissions-), so it's as simple as:

```
// ...
var myModule = require('./myModule');

myModule.init(function(err, acl) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // insert first `app.use()` here

  app.use(acl.middleware());

  // insert other middleware/route handlers here
});
```

Although I should note a couple of things with your existing code:

- `if (err) callback(err, acl);` should be changed to `if (err) return callback(err);` to prevent further execution after the callback is called.
- `if (error) return callback(error);` is missing right inside the `mongodb.connect()` callback in case there is a connection error.

Comment: That simple, thank you! One question left: Where should I put the module.exports in app.js?