# Export express app with asynchron middleware registration

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

According to my previous ask question ([How to register async middleware module within express.js app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719918/how-to-register-async-middleware-module-within-express-js-app)), I'd like to export my app with all middlewares, so that I can start a server with a start script like that:

```
var debug = require('debug')('MyApp');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
   debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

How do I export in my app.js? Would you prefer a different module architecture?